# Remove rows with date older than 30 days of specific date

Tags: r, date, dataframe

let's have a data frame:

```
date <- c("2019-01-03", "2017-02-03", "2018-12-30", "2018-08-12")
date <- as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
variable <- c(1,2, 100, 500)
df <- data.frame(date, variable)
```

And special, specific date:

```
special_date <- c("2019-01-04")
special_date <- as.Date(special_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

How to remove all rows with dates older than **30 days** of special_date?

```
#expected outcome
#        date variable
#1 2019-01-03        1
#3 2018-12-30      100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a logical condition in `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df, date > (special_date - 30))
#          date variable
#1 2019-01-03        1
#3 2018-12-30      100
```

---

Or with `filter` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   filter(date > (special_date - 30))
```